# String.Substring doesnt work when index greater than 100000

Tags: c#, string, substring

I am trying to split a string object in order to store it in a NO-SQL database where the per column storage capacity is no more than 64kb and my string is 220 kb long.

What I do is to split whatever string I have into segments. I am trying to split it in 4 like :

```
int howManyBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(serializedObject);
if (howManyBytes > 64000)
{
     //divide by 4
     int whereToSplit = Convert.ToInt32(howManyBytes * 0.25);
     returnValue.MethodReturnValue = serializedObject.Substring(0, whereToSplit);
     returnValue.MethodReturnValue2 = serializedObject.Substring(whereToSplit, whereToSplit * 2);
     returnValue.MethodReturnValue3 = serializedObject.Substring(whereToSplit * 2, whereToSplit * 3);
     returnValue.MethodReturnValue4 = serializedObject.Substring(whereToSplit * 3);
}
```

I am having problems when I want to do `returnValue.MethodReturnValue3 = serializedObject.Substring(whereToSplit * 2, whereToSplit * 3)`, having an exception of index out of range.
This problem occurs when the length of my string is 225358 and my whereToSplit is 56340.

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being flagged to close - it's a fairly well written question, with good code samples, showing that research has been done...

Comment: Instead of splitting the object evenly across four columns why don't code it in a away that fills columns entirely until it's out of data to write? Not only will you avoid rounding problems but it could work for strings of any "reasonable" length.

Comment: that seems like a good approach kittoes, I was unable to come up with some generic way to do the splitting but that helped out. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s second parameter is the length to return, not the second split position.  This can't be beyond the end of the string.  As such, it should be:

```
returnValue.MethodReturnValue = serializedObject.Substring(0, whereToSplit);
returnValue.MethodReturnValue2 = serializedObject.Substring(whereToSplit, whereToSplit); // No *2
returnValue.MethodReturnValue3 = serializedObject.Substring(whereToSplit * 2, whereToSplit); // No *3
returnValue.MethodReturnValue4 = serializedObject.Substring(whereToSplit * 3);
```

In addition, `225358 * 0.25` is actually `56339.5`, and getting rounded **up**.  You may want to take this into account, as your last string would end up shorter than the others.  (This may or may not matter, however, in your scenario.)

Comment: I noticed the roundup thats why in the last ".Substring" I did not specify the second parameter :) and thanks for the answer btw, It was not clear enough for me the descprition of the parameter on the documentation.